# Dolphin file deletion is slow

Tags: dolphin, plasma-5

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. I noticed right from installation that deleting files using Dolphin is very slow. Deleting a single 225 KiB file just now took 18 seconds for Dolphin to update the directory display. In all other respects, my system seems to be running at a reasonable pace. Any ideas what might be causing the delay?

Comment: What is the location of the files to be deleted? You could also try this: open dolphin and konsole; in konsole, start `top` and then, in dolphin, delete a file. See if `top` reveals a spike in CPU/RAM usage of some process(es).

Comment: @DKBose: Not sure of your question. The file was on my primary hard disk drive, ~/Documents/Notes/. I've noticed this happening in other directories as well, all on the same drive; but I don't have the same problem when deleting files through Emacs or konsole. I'll try your suggestion with `top` and see if anything shows up.

Comment: I couldn't figure out where the files to be deleted were located. For example, they could be on some external device which has slower r/w speed. I have an oldish Intel i3 CPU and a spinning hard-drive but I don't have any issue with deleting or moving or copying files. Do you empty your trash regularly?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug, since 2009, and there's no consistent way of fixing it.

Some people reduce its impact by, on preferences, deactivating the **trash quotas**. Or by deleting "**~/.config**".

What I do is using another file manager: **pcmanfm-qt**. It works substantially better.

Comment: Well, every other Linux file manager works substantially better. Compared to Nautilus, Thunar, Nemo or Caja, Dolphin trashes files at geologic speed.

Comment: @ChameleonScales It also happens with pcmanfm, as it also uses the same libs for handling files. It seems to affect a big chunk of file managers that share the same back-ends.